# pass function component with static property to highorder funtion and returned component lost static property

Tags: reactjs, typescript, properties, static, high-order-component

i passed a function component to high order component, the function component has some static property as the example! how can i get the static property from the returned component!

```
function TestHighOrderCp<T>(
  Cp: React.ComponentType<T>
): (
  props: T & {
    name: string
  }
) => JSX.Element {
  const rs = (props: T & { name: string }) => {
    const name = 'testName'
    return <Cp name={name} {...props} />
  }
  return rs
}

const A1 = function A1(props: { e: string }) {
  return <div>{props.e}</div>
}
A1.defaultProps = {
  e: 12
}
A1.name = '12'

const A11 = TestHighOrderCp<A1>
// A11.Name = {} // get Error here
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually copy static properties as it's not copied even when you spread props, `{...props}`.

Or you can use a helper library, [hoist-non-react-statics](https://github.com/mridgway/hoist-non-react-statics) to automatically copy all static properties to the wrapping component.

Check out this React documentation, [Static Methods Must Be Copied Over](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#static-methods-must-be-copied-over) for more info.